# How to get addon installed location in FF?

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, asynchronous, firefox-addon

I'm newbie in developing FF Extensions. I have downloaded javaDemo.xpi and tried to call java from javascript. But I'm stopped at

`Components.classes['@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager); is undefined`

I'm using FF 7.0.1. I have tried AddonManager API. But I couldn't find how to get the addon Location and got tired in handling asynchronous callback function.

```
Warning: WARN addons.manager: Exception calling callback: ReferenceError: alert is not defined
Source File: resource://javademo/LiveConnectUtils.js
Line: 65
```

Answer (score 1):

`nsIExtensionManager` API is only available up to Firefox 3.x, starting with Firefox 4 you need to use [the `AddonManager` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager). Something like this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID("me@mydomain.com", function(addon)
{
  var manifestURI = addon.getResourceURI("install.rdf");
  alert("Add-on's install.rdf is located at: " + manifestURI.spec);
});
```

Note that `manifestURI.spec` typically isn't a `file://` URL but rather a `jar:` URL - most extensions aren't unpacked upon installation so all extension files are inside a JAR (a.k.a. ZIP) file. You can use `XMLHttpRequest` or [`NetUtil.asyncFetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm#asyncFetch%28%29) to read these files regardless of what that URL points to.

Comment: I know i'm crazy..but i'm curious to know why "alert" function is not working in LiveConnectUtils.js in the javaDemo example?

Comment: @Samrat: Depending on the context in which your script executes there might not be an `alert()` function (particularly in XPCOM components or JavaScript modules). Which is why you should use [`dump()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.dump) or [`Components.utils.reportError()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.reportError), they are defined everywhere and don't have the problematic modal behavior of `alert()`.

Comment: Thanks. This boosts me in creating extensions.